# pipeline funtion can't take effect in Scrapy while using crontab

Tags: scrapy, cron

I'm using Scrapy to crawl some websites.I ran the code manually, and the it ran well(came into pipeline module and insert data into database).
  However, when I want to **run my code regularly using crontab in Ubuntu**, a problem occured.
  It did not came into pileline module(or the function I wrote in pipeline).
  What's can I do?
  Here is my part code:

```
**pipelines.py**
class PlatformnewsPipeline(object)
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        log.msg('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
```

It did not pirint '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~' in output in crontab while It did in manual mode.
The follow is my projct Settins:

```
DEFAULT_ITEM_CLASS = 'platformNews.items.PlatformnewsItem'

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'platformNews.pipelines.PlatformnewsPipeline': 300
}

crontab :
33 9,12,18 * * * python get_news.py >> log.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Can you please post your crontab entry?

Comment: 33 9,12,18 * * * python get_news.py >> log.log 2>&1

Comment: and whats in log.log?

Comment: Blank,just some initial info in scrapy .if pipeline works,it will print dozens of'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~' in my log.log, which I excute my file manually shows

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check.

1. You already said your pipeline isn't working. Have you checked if your spider is working? Try add logging in your spider.
2. Your crontab entry get_news.py is a relative path, is it really executed? or maybe python cannot find the file. Try full absolute path.

Comment: My spider is working , but do not come into pipelines . The absolute path of file in my crontab is cut ,I just show the file name.However,it works well when I **manually** excute file.

Answer (score 0):

`33 9,12,18 * * * cd your_project_dir_path && python get_news.py >> log.log 2>&1`

Hope to help others facing this problem.